# How to stop Treeview nodes appearing differently between WM5 & WM6.5

Tags: windows-mobile, treeview, windows-mobile-6, windows-mobile-6.5, windows-mobile-5.0

For some reason treeview nodes appear more spaced out on Windows Mobile 6.5 than on Windows Mobile 5.  This is true of both physical devices and when using the emulator.

On Windows Mobile 5

[image]

On Windows Mobile 6.5

[image]

Because of the tiny PDA screen it would be very useful to get rid of the white space, to allow more information to be displayed.

I am using the .Net Compact Framework 3.5, and I have seen this behaviour on Windows Mobile 6.5 and 6.5.3

Comment: Are both using the same size font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spacing is intentional and cannot be changed (without custom drawing the entire thing, which is [not so easy in managed code](http://christian-helle.blogspot.com/2009/10/listview-custom-drawing-in-netcf.html)), as WinMo 6.5 and later supposedly moved toward more "finger friendly" UIs.

I realize the link is for a ListView, but the TreeView in CE also supports custom drawing in the same way, and that link is the only custom drawn *anything* I've seen for the CF.